Is there a way to send an 2d array into a function without knowing its size before runtime?
I keep getting this error:

use of parameter outside function body before ']'

I googled it and found that you apparently can't do this. Is there another way of doing the same thing I tried here?
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char getAt(int x, int y, int size, char array[size][size]) {
    return array[x][y];
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    string curField;
    char exampleArray[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >>curField;
        strcpy(exampleArray[i], curField.c_str());
    }

    cout << getAt(1, 1, n, exampleArray) << endl;
}

I thought that you could define arrays at runtime, but apparently not in functions. I'm really new to C++ and still don't know how to do this kind of stuff.

char exampleArray[n][n] is not a valid C++ code.

char exampleArray[n][n]; -- See the error on line 15.  Using the right compiler options shows the error that has been pointed out.  Since you are probably using g++ or clang, make sure you compile using -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic, so that you don't make these mistakes.  It's too bad g++ and clang default to non-standard behavior.

A C-style array does not know its size. You either have to pass it (the size) or use a different container that does know it's size.

Note that the array tricks you are trying to use here are legal (but I think they are currently optional) in the C programming language. Use this experience as a counter argument next time someone tells you that C++ is a superset of C.

char exampleArray[n][n]; is a Variable Length Array, which is not standard C++, so avoid using it:
Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?
Use std::vector instead when you need an array whose size is not known at compile-time.  You can pass it around like any other variable.
Also, std::string is like a variable-length array of characters.  So, in this case, consider using a 1-dimensional std::vector<std::string>.
Try this:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

char getAt(int x, int y, const vector<string> &array) {
    return array[x][y];
    // note that vector::operator[] and string::operator[]
    // do not perform bounds checking, so if you want that
    // then use vector::at() and string::at() instead:
    //
    // return array.at(x).at(y);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<string> exampleArray(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> exampleArray[i];
    }

    cout << getAt(1, 1, exampleArray) << endl;
}

